# why am i receiving a print full of 'None'?

Tags: python, arrays, list, web-scraping

I am scraping a site, where i have a list of paragraphs inside a class.
when i print the just the text inside the paragraphs is all fine. But if i want to store them into a list, i receive a None.

To go through all those paragraphs i use the methode find_all with a loop. How can i proceed to receive the real text, string and to store it into a list.

```
listagoala = []

col_moneda = container_fluid.find('div', class_='col-sm-2 hidden-xs')

moneda = col_moneda.find_all('p')

for paragraphs in moneda:
    listaplina = listagoala.append(paragraphs.text)
    print(listaplina)
```

OUTPUT:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply do

```
listagoala = []

col_moneda = container_fluid.find('div', class_='col-sm-2 hidden-xs')

moneda = col_moneda.find_all('p')

for paragraphs in moneda:
    listagoala.append(paragraphs.text)
    print(listagoala) # Using print here will print multiple lists, as this is inside loop

print(listagoala) # print the final list with all elements
```

You don't have to do

```
listaplina = listagoala.append(paragraphs.text)
```

`listagoala.append(paragraphs.text)` will work.

---

Just for your explanation:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [5,6,7,8]
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Comment: my final list must have 16 elements. The outpout is with 16 lists where the first list has 1 lement the second one 2 elemtnts ... the 16th one has 16 elements, so is not the best output.
 i am not very familiar with the data structures... sorry for those stupid questions.

Comment: Not getting exactly what you mean here. 
Did you said the output is 16 different lists?

Comment: yes, I should have a sigle list with 16 elements. but i have 16 lists. The first list has 1 element the second list has 2 elements .... until the 16th list which has 16 elements...

Comment: so from this output i would need just the last list, that with 16 elements

Comment: @mihai IDK why you're getting 16 different lists, can you post the complete code please. Maybe you're doing something else wrong

Comment: you are right, i am stupid. The indentation was bad. the print statement must has the same level indentation like the for.

Comment: @mihai I've added the comments for the print too. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Note to the reader: This answer refers to the original version of the question that had the following line: `listaplina = [paragraphs.text].extend(listagoala)`.*

`list.extend()` doesn't return the modified list.  It returns `None` (having modified the list in place).

It sounds like you're looking for the following:

```
listaplina = [paragraphs.text] + listagoala
```

Comment: Sorry that was another try, but i will try your code, thanks!

Comment: @mihai: Please don't keep changing your question. This invalidates the answers and penalises those who are trying to help you.

Comment: The output is almost good. But the result is made by 16 lists, each of them with just 1 element. I would like to store theme into a single list.